# How do I add to NSDictionary without worrying about the indices? Effectively an NSArray with multiple elements per index. Is there a better solution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures, nsarray, nsdictionary

Basically, in the end I want something like this, similar to JSON:

```
1: {
    "url": "http://...",
    "id": 8373
}
2: {
    "url": "https://...",
    "id": 1449
}
```

Where it's effectively an NSArray, but each index has two elements. It could be accomplished by two NSArrays and just accessing the same index in both, but this seems cleaner.

The only issue is that with NSArray (well, NSMutableArray), you can use `addObject` and it automatically adds it to the end, but *I can't figure out how to do this with NSDictionary*.

I know part of the issue with this is that NSDictionary doesn't maintain order, and I don't care, it doesn't need to, but I want to be able to automatically add pairs of data to some data structure and be able to access it later.

Is it possible to do that with NSDictionary? Should I be using some other data structure?

Comment: Have you considered using an NSMutableArray of NSDictionary objects?

Comment: Or an NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableArray objects? Where each key is like you have above, "1", "2", etc. The NSMutableArrays can store the strings of data you need and whenever you want to change them, just retrieve them from the dictionary and modify the arrays ( which is why I said NSMutableArray).

Comment: @user1274223 It would be much better to use a dictionary to hold the url and id. It's more flexible and more self documenting. Using an array requires you to know what value is in which index.

Comment: @Maudicus Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking of. Doh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either way you want to add a dictionary to "something", either an array or another dictionary.

With an array of dictionary you can do something like:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:@{ @"url" : @"http://....", @"id" : @373 }];
```

or with a dictionary of dictionary you can do:

```
myMutableDictionary[@1] = @{ @"url" : @"http://....", @"id" : @373 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an NSMutableDictionary and `setObject:forKey:`?  That or I would create a class that has two properties (url and id) and add that to my NSMutableArray.